# How to say idiomatically "all the celebrities in the world" in French in this context?

Tags: expressions

> **Tout ce que le monde compte de** célébrités passe un jour ou l’autre par Saint Barth…. Il m’est arrivé de croiser très souvent Laetitia et Johnny Halliday. Ils faisaient leurs courses, et moi les miennes.

The rather literally translated "toutes les célébrités dans le monde passent ..." sounds odd to my ears, as if excluding the possibility of any exception to the stereotypical behaviours of celebrities.

I wonder if "tout ce que le monde compte de X" is one of the idiomatic phrasings to express this idea — even if it is not  mentioned anywhere that these two are equivalents of each other.

Answer (score 3):

Hmm, it seems from your question that you are attempting to translate from French to French... anyway, you are right to state:

> Toutes les célébrités dans le monde passent...

is unidiomatic.

What works is:

> Toutes les célébrités du monde passent...
>
> Toutes les célébrités mondiales passent...

but:

> Tout ce que le monde compte de célébrités passe...

is better as it places a stronger emphasis on the subject.